# Mongodb stopped working after authorization

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, authentication, mongoose

Everything worked fine when I used:
`mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/data`.
After add authentication with database: `mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/?authSource=data` stops working.

Before that I fill database `data` and created a new user:

```
use data
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "user",
    pwd: "pwd",
    roles: [
       { role: "dbAdmin", db: "data" },
    ]
  }
)
db.grantRolesToUser(
   "user",
   [ "readWrite" , { role: "read", db: "data" } ],
   { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 4000 }
)
```

And I changed `mongod.cfg` file:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

But it doesn't work anyway, the backend connects to the database but the requests are empty as if backend doesn't have access to the data from database.

server.js in backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const db = "mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/?authSource=data";
const PORT = 3000;
const api = require('./routes/api');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api', api);

mongoose
    .connect(db, {
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to mongodb!'))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(Error, err.message);
    });

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('Server running on localhost:' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: Are you able to query the same data from any of the tools like `mongo` shell or Compass with the new user/pwd?

Comment: I am using Compass and this url works fine and there is a base there, everything looks fine in Compass

Comment: _" the backend connects to the database but the requests are empty"_ - What is your request route code?

Comment: What do you mean with request route? I pasted this connection string `mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/?authSource=data` and connect. After connected I see my `data` database.

Comment: Is your NodeJS backend application connecting to the database? Are you seeing the console.logged: 'Connected to mongodb!'

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing in console `Connected to mongodb!` but in application I see on req `This request has no response data available`. But if I change connection string to `mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/data` there is data

Comment: The `db.grantRolesToUser`method parameters - can you verify they are correct?

Comment: How to verify it?

Comment: What is the `username` parameter value in your posted code for the method `db.grantRolesToUser` and the method `createUser`? _The values need to be same._

Comment: What do you mean with parameter value in my posted code? My username of user mongodb is just `user`.

Comment: It should be same for both the methods. Your code `db.grantRolesToUser("data",...` has "data" in it instead of "user". See the usage of [db.grantRolesToUser()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/).

Comment: Ohh sorry, it was the same, by mistake I wrote it wrong in the question, but in the console I used `user` in both cases

Comment: You changed your question post now. The reason for your issue is mostly because of passing the wrong value to the grantRolesToUser method.

Comment: Yes, because it's not a problem, just mistake in question, do you have any other ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Did you restart your `mongod` instance with authorization after you created the user (I see you have changed the config file)?

Comment: No, how to do it?

Comment: When you enable authentication then you must create an admin user in the `admin` database. This admin user must have at least role `{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },` see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: See this post for some info: [for mongo, not able to create users other than admin with error command createUser requires authentication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292514/for-mongo-not-able-to-create-users-other-than-admin-with-error-command-createus/292519#292519).

Comment: Also see this doc: [Enable Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it all and let you know

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I did everything according to the instructions, created the administrator, then changed the config file to enable authorization, logged in as administrator and still no connection to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The reason was `authSource` in connection string.

Before:

```
 "connectionString": "mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/?authSource=data"
```

After:

```
 "connectionString": "mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/data"
```

Now it's working fine.